# Changing the output of a query - Find replace

Tags: mysql

I want to change some field's values in the output of a query. Can this be done with derived tables?

Here's my attempt...

```
update t.Artist,

(SELECT Artist FROM mydb.mytable group by Artist) as t

set Artist = replace(Artist,'&','&amp;');
```

Basically, I have some non escaped data that I need to process with XSL. I can't escape the data (it will break another service), so am looking to work around with the above query.

So the subquery might return...

```
Artist
Michael Jackson
Donald & Mickey
```

I want the query to return...

```
Artist
Michael Jackson
Donald &amp; Mickey
```

Without changing the raw data in `mydb.mytable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with sub-queries, however your action looks a bit strange. It looks like you want to update a table (that is what the update statement is for).

Your result can be achieved with just:

```
SELECT replace(Artist,'&','&amp;') AS Artist FROM mydb.mytable group by Artist;
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. I thought I had to use an Update query, which lead me down the path of subqueries and derived tables. This is much more simple and elegant. Probably trivial now that I think about it!